# What technology to get NTFS access rights in C?

Tags: c, security, winapi, acl, ntfs

I am thinking hard about how to play with access rights on several platforms. Now I am reaching Microsoft Windows and permissions on NTFS files/directories.

I must say that I am working in C language. My question is pretty general. I have a username and a file path.

Do I need more information to check if the user has the right to read/write/execute ?

What technology should I use ? ACLs or basic Win32 API ? Something else ?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: I would like to know the answer for this question using C and linux. How can we (without windows API) check for file rights in C?

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the Windows API in that case?

GetSecurityInfo from the platform SDK should help. It returns the owner, groups etc. that are associated with the object (not only files and directories). You then need to further check the returned information against your given username.